# Cannot Create new Post within Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I have a custom post type registered and when registering I am using...

```
if( !post_type_exists( 'email_template' ) ) {
            register_post_type( 'email_template',
                array(
                    'labels'    => array(
                        'name'               => _x( 'Email Templates', 'post type general name', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Email Template', 'post type singular name', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Email Templates', 'admin menu', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Email Template', 'add new on admin bar', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                        'add_new'            => __( 'Add Template', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Template', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                        'new_item'           => __( 'New Template', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Template', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                        'view_item'          => __( 'View Template', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                        'all_items'          => __( 'All Templates', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Templates', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                        'not_found'          => __( 'No templates found.', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No templates found in Trash.', 'mobile-dj-manager' ) ),
                    'description'           => __( 'Email Templates for the Mobile DJ Manager plugin', 'mobile-dj-manager' ),
                    'public'                 => false,
                    'exclude_from_search'   => true,
                    'publicly_queryable'     => true,
                    'show_ui'               => true,
                    'show_in_menu'         => 'edit.php?post_type=email_template',
                    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
                    'query_var'           => true,
                    'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'email-template' ),
                    'capability_type'       => 'mdjm_template',
                    'capabilities'           => array(
                        'edit_post'             => 'edit_mdjm_template',
                        'read_post'             => 'read_mdjm_template',
                        'delete_post'           => 'delete_mdjm_template',
                        'edit_posts'            => 'edit_mdjm_templates',
                        'edit_others_posts'     => 'edit_others_mdjm_templates',
                        'publish_posts'         => 'publish_mdjm_templates',
                        'read_private_posts'    => 'read_private_mdjm_templates'
                    ),
                    'map_meta_cap'         => true,
                    'has_archive'           => true,
                    'hierarchical'             => false,
                    'menu_position'           => 5,
                    'supports'             => array( 'title', 'editor', 'revisions' ) ) );
        }
```

to register the post type.

I have confirmed using User Role Editor that my user has all of the *_mdjm_template caps and yet the user cannot create a new post. The only other cap this role has is 'read'. The New post button is displayed but clicking it renders the "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." message.

All other functionality within this post type works fine. i.e. The user can see all posts and edit them. Just not create new ones.

What have I missed?

**EDIT**

I am adding the caps to a user role that was created during plugin activation using the below...

```
$role = get_role( 'my_role' );
$caps = array( 
    'mdjm_template_edit' => true, 'edit_mdjm_template' => true,
    'read_mdjm_template' => true, 'delete_mdjm_template' => true, 'edit_mdjm_templates' => true,
    'edit_others_mdjm_templates' => true, 'publish_mdjm_templates' => true, 'read_private_mdjm_templates' => true,
    'edit_published_mdjm_templates' => true, 'edit_private_mdjm_templates' => true, 'delete_mdjm_templates' => true,
    'delete_others_mdjm_templates' => true, 'delete_private_mdjm_templates' => true,
    'delete_published_mdjm_templates' => true
);

foreach( $caps as $cap => $val )    {
    if( empty( $val ) )
        $role->remove_cap( $cap );
    else
        $role->add_cap( $cap );
}
```

**Output of user caps to error log whilst trying to create new post***

Signed in as user with the appropriate role and using `current_user_can( '$cap' )`

```
mdjm_template_edit: Has Cap
edit_mdjm_template: Does not have Cap
read_mdjm_template: Does not have Cap
delete_mdjm_template: Does not have Cap
edit_mdjm_templates: Has Cap
edit_others_mdjm_templates: Has Cap
publish_mdjm_templates: Has Cap
read_private_mdjm_templates: Has Cap
edit_published_mdjm_templates: Has Cap
edit_private_mdjm_templates: Has Cap
delete_mdjm_templates: Has Cap
delete_others_mdjm_templates: Has Cap
delete_private_mdjm_templates: Has Cap
delete_published_mdjm_templates: Has Cap
```

Comment: Can an admin user create a post? Is the user who can't create a post a standard user or one with customized role/privileges?

Comment: Its a custom role with only read caps from the default WP caps but all the custom caps for the post type.
Admin is fine and can create new custom posts without issue

Comment: You may know this already, but -- the array code in your example is just what provides post-type-specific names to each of the capabilities. Toggling those capabilities is done in your User Role Editor. I suspect you will need to provide more information on the User Role Editor settings.

Comment: Also -- can the user in question Create New regular posts?

Comment: The user cannot create other post types. The only caps this role has are the *_mdjm_template(s) caps and the built in 'read' cap.

I updated the original post to include the full `register_post_type` function

Comment: Can you show exactly how you are adding the required capabilities to the user role?  Also, are you simply adding capabilities to an existing role or are you creating a custom role via the add_role function in wp?  If the latter, you need to delete the role and re-add it if you ever need to change the capabilities.  It'll short-circuit to doing nothing if the role is already found in the database.

Comment: The role is created during plugin activation. Code for adding the caps to the role is now within the original post

Comment: How about checking the user's capabilities via a call to 'user_can(...)' -- echo it or write it to PHP error log -- just to see if in fact the user has the capabilities you think he has, at the time needed.

Comment: also...which hook are you tied into, for executing that code to add the capabilities to the role?

Comment: The caps are assigned following a form post which is captured via the init hook.

I checked all the possible caps for this post type and output to the error log. I added them to the original post as too many chars for comment

Comment: WP caps continue to confuse me.... Seems I simply need to give my custom roles the edit_post, delete_post and read caps as minimum. I was only setting read. This does make sense now (eventually). I'm thinking I now need to use the `map_meta_cap` filter for more granular control but that's a task for tomorrow!

Comment: You should only need to use map_meta_cap for very specific things, like modifying capabilities based on context (e.g. posts of a certain date or custom field value).  I am working on a plugin that does very similar to what you are doing here, only difference is I use **add_role()** and do not mess around with add_cap.  Probably because I had issues...